# Array of dynamic structs containing views

Tags: swift, swiftui

How do you create an array of structs which all might have a different partial userinterface?
The idea is, that I can have a dynamic list of blocks, and whichever block is activated, the according UI (so the view of the block's content attribute) is displayed.

So far I have the following struct:

```
struct Block<Content: View> {
    var name: String
    var symbol: String

    var content: () -> Content

    init(name: String, symbol: String, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.name = name
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.content = content
    }
}
```

I tried to initialize an array like so:

```
let blocks: [Block] = [
    Block(name: "block 1", symbol: "b1") {
       HStack{Text("t1") Button("b1"){}}
    },
    Block(name: "block 2", symbol: "b2", content: Text("t1")),
    Block(name: "block 3", symbol: "b3", content: Text("t1")),
    // ...
]
```

This aproach gives me the following error:
Cannot assign value of type '[Block]' to type '[Block]'

Comment: Generics is part of type, so you cannot do array of heterogenous types content. You will need type erasure for that, like `AnyView`, but it is not good way. So it is better to keep data & views separated. But it is your way...

Comment: I agree in that data and view should be separated. But in this particular case I do have within a view a dynamic list of options and whatever option is selected, additional content is required. And this will require very different views. I thought just creating an array of those views and all the aditional data might be better than having a very long if ..  elseif .. elseif...  for all the options in the view. Or am I thinking in the wrong direction here? I'm not experienced with swift and some concepts are indeed diffferent from what I'm used to

Comment: I don't get what you think you need an array of Bock for. What you need is an array of the _data model_ needed to make each Block. — Keep in mind that everything is against you: you can't make an array of generics, View is a protocol and you can't make an array of a protocol, and a View is not even really a thing — it's just a momentary set of instructions for describing the interface. Swift UI is about the flow of the _data_ so make an array of the _data_.

Comment: As I said, each block comes with completely different requirements for the ui, you could think of it as different input forms. It's not that each block is just a instance of one data model.

Comment: You've been told twice that your approach isn't the right one. Data is what drives the view, so if you have different type of data, you can create a view using a conditional or a `switch`. If you believe that your case is somehow different, edit your question to clarify why what's been suggested would not work

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, I've created now a own view for each block to make the code not too messy. So now I have a big switch/case over all these sub-views. Is this really better than using an array with all these views of type AnyView? Sorry for my mindset here, I'm new to swift & swiftui and rather used to create dynamic UI's :D

Comment: +1 to everything the others have previously said, you should *never*, *ever* store SwiftUI views into collections, properties/etc. The nature of SwiftUI is to generate the actual screen rendering views based on the view builders, and not of some stored views. You are trying to define UIKit behaviour in terms of SwiftUI, which is neither possible nor recommended.